# thread visibility issue: if I run multithreads on one cpu only.if exieted variable visibity issue?

Tags: java, multithreading

as titled:
thread visibility issue: if I run multithreads on one cpu only.if exieted variable visibity issue?
I think the threads will share the cache and not have any visibility , any other opinion ?
Thanks at advanced.

Answer (score 2):

Just concern yourself with the [Java Memory Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Memory_Model) - details of CPU architectures (caches etc) are abstracted away from you and are handled transparently by the JVM.

> The Java Memory Model (JMM) defines the allowable behavior of multithreaded programs [...] It places execution-time constraints on the relationship between threads and main memory in order to achieve consistent and reliable Java applications. By doing this, it makes it possible to reason about code execution in a multithreaded environment, even in the face of optimizations performed by the dynamic compiler, the processor(s) and the caches.

Java is cross-platform, and so you can't rely on the characteristics of one particular single-core machine.

See also: [Fixing the Java Memory Model, Part 2](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp03304/) by Brian Goetz.

Comment: thanks, I know we can't rely on any special machine. In fact, I want to know if there is one cpu. many thread if have visibility issue?